# Необходимо удалить каждую вторую букву в слове (c#)

Tags: c#, строки

Преобразовать пользовательский ввод в указанный шаблон: уаиь кжу воую бку в сое (удалить каждую вторую букву в слове)

Не могу разобраться с циклом. Действие происходит только с последним словом.

```
Console.WriteLine("Введите предложение: ");
        string str = Console.ReadLine();
        string text = "";
        string[] words = str.Split(new char[] { ' ' });
        foreach (string s in words)
        {
            
            for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
            {

                if (i % 2 != 0)
                {
                    text = str.Remove(i, 1);
                }
                                   
            }
                            
        }
        Console.WriteLine(text);
```

Comment: Linq проходили?

Comment: к сожалению нет(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Text;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Введите предложение: ");
        var words = Console.ReadLine().Split();
        var rez = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (var word in words) {
            // берем буквы с нужным индексом из каждого слова
            for (int i = 0; i< word.Length; i+=2)
            {
                rez.Append(word[i]);
            }
            // вставляем пробел между словами
            rez.Append(" ");
        }
        
        Console.WriteLine(rez);
    }
}
```

проще будет через линк, но линк вряд ли преподаватель пропустит